# typescript union type with various interfaces

Tags: typescript, tslint, union-types

I'm trying to define an object model that contains an object. This object can be of two diferent types of object.

```
export interface EventParams {
    evtType: string;
    evtData: FaultOrGoalData| SwapData;
}

export interface FaultOrGoalData {
    evtName: string;
    player: string;
    position: string;
}

export interface SwapData {
    swapPlayer: string;
}
```

My problem here is ts lint telling me that it's impossible to access the data contained in an encapsulated object.

Example: `params.evtData.evtName`

Hence my question: is it possible to create a union type with interfaces?

Comment: Can you include the actual code that breaks?  If you're just blithely trying to use `params.evtData.evtName` without checking if `params.evtData` is a `FaultOrGoalData` first, that's the sort of error TypeScript is designed to catch.  If you *are* checking, and TypeScript is still reporting an error, then it might not be one of the checks the compiler understands.  As it stands, the answer to your question is: "yes it is possible, and the error you're getting is a good one".

Comment: it is an error I'm getting with tslint before runtime. So I believe at this point it doesn't matter what's actually in the object

Comment: Yes, TypeScript compiler errors happen before runtime, but they warn about problems you expect to see at runtime.  In this case, the error is saying "I don't know that `params.evtData` is going to have an `evtName` member, so I'm complaining about it now."  @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's answer is one way to deal with the error.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can create a union with interfaces, you just did, but you can only access **common members** of the union. You can use a type guard to narrow the type and then you can access specific members. In this case you could use an `in` type guard:

```
declare let foo: EventParams;
if('evtName' in foo.evtData) {
    foo.evtData.evtName //foo.evtData is of type FaultOrGoalData
}else {
    foo.evtData.swapPlayer // foo.evtData is of type SwapData
}
```